# Unable to locate and use manual installed Python

Tags: ubuntu, apt, python3

I installed latest Python 3.10 using this command:

```
sudo apt install python3.10
```

But unable to use it.

When I am running the same command, getting this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'postgresql-plpython3-10' for regex 'python3.10'
postgresql-plpython3-10 is already the newest version (10.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

Please help me on how to locate and use installed Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't install Python 3.10, because Python 3.10 is not available for Ubuntu 18.04 (at least in the official Ubuntu repositories where it is [available only for 21.04 and newer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.10)). And because exact match is not available `apt` interpreted `python3.10` as a regular expression and decided to install matching `postgresql-plpython3-10` package:

> Note, selecting 'postgresql-plpython3-10' for regex 'python3.10'

If you want to install Python 3.10 on 18.04 you can use the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

and then install `python3.10`.

Comment: @NawinKSharma could you unmark this answer? it's no longer correct

Answer (score 4):

As of June 6, 2023, this will no longer be possible.

https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues/251

The maintainers of deadsnakes have decided to delete all Ubuntu 18 packages, versus simply letting them exist as-is while not offering new ones. It's a disappointing decision, because Ubuntu 18 is still in ESM support, and all existing updates for base packages up thru May 31 can still be downloaded and applied as normal. It's just that new security updates require a paid ESM subscription. Not so with deadsnakes.